# TI-84: call a function from the catalog with z88dk

Tags: c, assembly, ti-basic, z80

I'm programming my TI-84 in C with z88dk. I need to call things like normalcdf and Ztest. I know they can be called from ti-BASIC, but how do I call them from C or inline assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TI-84 assembly, you use the `BCALL` or `B_CALL` instruction to do a "system call" into the TI-84's ROM. This is usually used for simple I/O things (`B_CALL PutS` prints a string to the screen), but it could also be for more complicated mathematical routines (`LD A,OPNormal; B_CALL BinOPExec` computes the `normalcdf(` function).

Google ["ti-84 bcall BinOPExec"](http://www.google.com/#output=search&q=ti84+bcall+binopexec) for more information on `B_CALL`.

Comment: Thanks. yeesh this is going to be fun to figure out

Comment: @deepthought If this solved your problem, please "accept" this answer, to keep your question from coming up as "Unanswered" and of course to give me karma. ;) Thanks!